# Move all files except the last n files

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I move everything but the last `n` files, from `dir1` to `dir2`?.

I currently do this, setting the time as an approximate for `n`, in my case `n=2` each 10 minutes.

```
find /dir1/ -name '*.txt*' -mmin +10 -type f -exec mv "{}" /dir2/ \;
```

A similar command, could work, but i am not certain, could somebody confirm how should adapt this?

```
ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' mv -f --
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux

Comment: So you are suggesting that the solution is `ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' mv -f --`?